# Removing the old bundle from ARP when upgrading SKUs

Tags: wix, installation, burn

I'm deploying two CDs, and thinking both will have a setup.exe bundle.

One CD will be called "standard SKU" and setup.exe will install a.msi, and b.msi.

The other CD will be called "pro SKU" and setup.exe will install a.msi, b.msi, and c.msi.

What is the proper procedure when authoring the setup.exe files?  Specifically, for the scenario where somebody installed the standard SKU, and then installed the pro SKU on top; would this be considered a related bundle/upgrade?  Just install both bundles and keep both entries in ARP?  Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't try to use upgrades here but related bundles is definitely the place to start. In this case, I would have the two Bundles share a `RelatedBundle` id and `Tag` them appropriately. Add something like the following to the "standard" Bundle:

```
<Bundle ... Tag='standard'>

   <RelatedBundle Id='PUT-SAME-GUID-HERE' Action='Detect' />
```

Do the same for the "pro" Bundle but `Tag` it appropriately.

Now, in your custom bootstrapper application, on the `OnDetectRelatedBundle()` you'll get a callback when if one of the Bundles is already installed. That callback will also send back the `Tag` so you'll know which Bundle was present. You can display the result to the user or whatever if you like. The real important part is that during the `OnPlanRelatedBundle()` callback, you'll want to return the appropriate `RequestState` to say whether to remove or leave the found Bundle.

Good luck, all the data is there, just a matter of getting the right callbacks.